# Showing a specific amount of tags

Tags: laravel

I have a list of tags in the database it has 15 words. I just wanted to pull out the first 3.For example say that I have apple,grapes,cookies,candy,milk as my tags I only want to show apples,grapes and cookies How do I do that? I tried this but it's the thing is it leaves out the rest of the letters. By the way, I am using laravel. Thanks in advance
here is code

`{{ str_limit(rtrim($users->tags,','),'36',("")) }}`

This is the output that I get

Makeup artist, hairstylist, airbrus

Comment: *"but it's not giving me the results I want."* Well what results is it giving you? What does `dd($users->tags);` return? We're gonna need a lot more information to help with this.

Comment: @TimLewis I edited my  question.

Comment: Yeah, but not really... I'll reiterate. What results is it giving you? What does that line of code output? Also, what does `dd($users->tags);` return? Explaining the issue is not the same as showing the specific input/output of your code, so please include that.

Comment: @TimLewis I edited again. The $users->tags return the list of tags

Comment: *"The $users->tags return the list of tags"* Obviously... What does that list look like??? I mean I can kinda guess it at from your output of "Makeup artist, hairstylist, airbrus", but is there any reason you can't just include that in your question? Really makes it difficult to help you lol...

Comment: Look I'm sorry I didn't know how to word the question. I just want to show just the first 3 words from the tags but not all of it. For example say that I have apple,grapes,cookies,candy,milk as my tags I only want to show apples,grapes and cookies

Comment: There you go; that comments explains it perfectly :) So there's a lot of different ways to handle that. I think the mistake you're making is assuming that 36 characters will be enough for 3 tags, when the data is dynamic. I'll show you what I would do.

Comment: @TimLewis Ok thank you, again I'm sorry for not being clear the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given the `$user->tags` string of

```
apple, orange, kiwi, lemon, pineapple
```

Attempting to split and limit based on a single length won't work, as the data will be dynamic and result in a partial or incomplete tag. To get around this, use `explode()`:

```
$tags = explode(",", $user->tags); // ["apple", "orange", "kiwi", "lemon", "pineapple"];
```

Now that `$tags` is an array, it should be easier to take 3 and return them:

```
$firstThree = array_splice($tags, 0, 3); // ["apple", "orange", "kiwi"];
```

Now, that your `$tags` array contains 3 elements (or less, depending on what's in `$user->tags`), you can `implode()` it into a string:

```
$tagString = implode(",", $firstThree); // apple, orange, kiwi
```

Next, put it all together. In your case, this is likely easier done as a function of your `$user`:

```
public function tagString(){
  $tags = explode(",", $this->tags);
  $firstThree = array_splice($tags, 0, 3);
  return implode(",", $firstThree);
}
```

And, in your blade file:

```
{{ $user->tagString() }}
```

And that would do it!

Again, lots of ways to do this. An argument could be made for a simple regex to limit the value of `$user->tags` to the first 3 instances of `word,`, but Regex isn't my area of expertise. Hope that helps!

Comment: its kind of tricky doing it like that because of the way I set it up. We cant just just use array_slice in the view like this; {{ array_splice($users->tags, 0, 3) }}

Comment: Is your `$user` not a `Model`? You can definitely use base php in your `.blade.php` (`<?php $tags  = ...; ?>` is perfectly valid syntax in `.blade.php` files)

Comment: Oh okay. I put it like this but I think I did it wrong cause I keep getting error message <?php 
$tagString = implode(",", $firstThree); // apple, orange, kiwi
public function tagString(){
  $tags = explode(",", $this->tags);
  $firstThree = array_splice($tags, 0, 3);
  return implode(",", $firstThree);
  {{ $user->tagString() }}

}
?>

Comment: Do you have a `User.php` file under `app`? If you do, then `public function tagString()` should go there, not in your `.blade.php` file, then you can call `$user->tagString()`

Comment: @Time Lewis Oh lol okay! I got it thank you!!!! I marked you answer as the best. You solved my problem!!!!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)